# Set a default value to a property and make it serializable

Tags: c#, .net, properties, default, serializable

I need to set a default value for a property, but I can't do it like this:

```
private int prop = 1;

public Prop
{
     get { return prop;} ...
}
```

Because I need to serialize this class, and if I do it, I loose the default value.

Are you aware of any solution that works after the serialization and before, adding an attribute to the property?

I'm working with c# with framework 3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

```
[DefaultValue("SomeValue")]
public string Prop { get; set; }
```

You can read a lot about serialization here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: the DefaultValue Attribute is to tell to the property pages that is the default value expected for a property, maybe my question is wrong, I need to set the "Initial value" and persist this value after the serialization.

In your sample code, If I ask for the value of Prop I get string.Empty, not "SomeValue".

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Take a look a the OnSerializingAttribute instead.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to use the OnSerializationAttribute, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is also:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The defaults size for the list item.
    ''' </summary>
''' <value>Size.</value>
''' <returns>Size.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Category("Appearance")> _
<Description("The defaults size for the list item.")> _
  Public Property DefaultItemSize() As Size Implements IVisualList.DefaultItemSize
    Get
        Return m_DefaultItemSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Size)
        m_DefaultItemSize = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overridable Function ShouldSerializeDefaultItemSize() As Boolean
    If m_DefaultItemSize.Equals(New Size(100, m_CellHeight)) Then Return False
    Return True
End Function
```

or

Another option may be to use these attributes:

[OnSerializing()]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx

[OnDeserializing()]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx

Comment: I can't use custom serializators. The idea is to make an Entity class that includes information about constraints and other things. 

For example. I need to create an entity class named "Person", with a "name" property. And on an other property (for example name_MaxLength" and I want to specify the max length for the "name" property and use this property into the UI, bussines rules, validators, dinamic creation of store procedures... But, when I use this entity with webservices I loose the initial value, because I only have the scheema of the entity class, I don't have the implementation.